# I got some issues with my graphic card / driver or what is this?

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

My notebook: MSI GS40 6QE (16 GB RAM version)

Installed: NVIDIA 376.33

It might not be easy to make it clear by explaining but I got some issues with my graphic card or something else, or maybe it's alright but Windows is the guilty one...

So if I open specific software, not from a big company like Microsoft, the graphic is horrible, very cloudy actually. While on other sites, like this one, the graphic is perfectly fine.

Please help me saying what could be wrong, I have paid a lot money for this notebook and I want it be worth it .. : /

I will try to post some screens to show.

Here this is fine (the jpg ruins it of course):

[image]

Here very bad, I was about installing adobe pdf reader, look how bad it looks, the graphic (background and prog icons seem fine though):

[image]

Also on some websites, not just programs the graphic is not satisfying, look at the youtube icon (over the video left):

[image]

Left is good, right is bad..

[image]

Comment: I have no idea what you ask. What is wrong with the graphic? For me it looks fine

Comment: I post other example in 1 min and you see better.

Comment: You see difference now? On my computer it's easy to see but the jpg format makes it harder for you.

Comment: this is expected. Those are DPI scaling issues. in the Windows 10 creators update in march 2017, the MMC snapins are now DPI aware. Try the latest insider build to see the diff: https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2016/12/07/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-14986-pc/

Comment: if you only use FHD set the scaling to 100%, this laos fixes it, but the icons could be to tiny for you

Comment: I've posted my comments in an answer so that you can accept it if it answer your question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Answer (score 0):

What you see are DPI scaling issues of win32 applications. It looks like your 14" Display with Full HD resolution runs at 125% scaling.

With the Windows 10 creators update, which should be released in march/april 2017, [Microsoft makes MMC now DPI aware](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2016/12/07/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-14986-pc/):

> With the release of Build 14986 to Windows Insiders, we’re very
>   excited to share the next part in that story. Windows Insiders with
>   high DPI devices, such as the Surface Book, will now see improved
>   crispness in the text of a number of desktop applications that
>   previously would display blurry – in particular Microsoft Management
>   Console (MMC) snap ins like Device Manager.

Here is a [also video that shows it](https://twitter.com/shanselman/status/808790792374341632).

What you can do in V1607 is to set the [scaling to 100%](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5990-dpi-scaling-level-displays-change-windows-10-a.html), but here the icons may be very tiny on a 14" screen.